# How does laser induced fluorescence in excited atoms work?

Tags: measurements, laser, atomic-excitation

Atomic clocks use laser induced fluorescence in order to detect excited atoms, how does this work?

Apparently the clocks need to detect the states of nearly 100% of the atoms being examined. In an atomic fountain clock, a gas of Cesium atoms is excited and then a probe laser causes the altered atoms to fluoresce. I don't know how this would work or how they could be so accurate in knowing how many atoms were excited.

Comment: What is the question about? Laser-induced fluorescence in general or specifically about atomic clocks?

Answer (score -1):

Brief Overview: The chemist puts a laser on a sample. The atoms in the sample gain energy and for a few nano seconds it shines a light and returns to ground state. People such as agricultural inspectors use this to indentify any chemi